# Get documents inside the folder from Shared Document using powershell

Tags: powershell, folder

I need to get all the documents name inside the folder from shared document using power shell.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this script

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea 0


$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity "weburl"


$rfolder=$web.Lists["Shared Documents"].RootFolder
GetFiles($rfolder)

Function GetFiles($folder)
{ 
   Write-Host "+"$folder.Name
   foreach($file in $folder.Files)
   {
       Write-Host "`t" $file.Name
   }

   # Use recursion to loop through all subfolders.
   foreach ($subFolder in $folder.SubFolders)
   {
       Write-Host "`t" -NoNewline
       GetFiles($Subfolder)
   }
 }
```

You might also find some more usefull info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024103/how-to-retrieve-a-recursive-directory-and-file-list-from-powershell-excluding-so

Answer (score 0):

```
$web.Lists["Documents"].RootFolder.SubFolders["Your Folder Name"].Files
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But actually i want to get the files inside the folder from Shared Documents library in one of the site. I don't want to provide the folder name. It should find folder automatically.

Comment: @Ishani, there can be plenty of folders inside the library. The script needs to know some kinda logic to get files from a particular folder.